ESP32-CAM infinite boot loop
I am currently using an ESP32-CAM with an OV5460 camera, and I am interfacing it with my computer using an Arduino nano. I am trying to run a camera web server and using the Arduino example code. I have looked at a couple of YouTube tutorials and so have downloaded all the necessary stuff required to run an ESP32 project on Aurdino and have triple check all connectionss are correct. I am using the AI Thinker camera model. The problem comes in when I download the sketch and run it, I am greeted with some kind of CPU restart boot loop that just loops infinitely
What does this mean? How to fix it?
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57
rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0030,len:1288
load:0x40078000,len:13872
load:0x40080400,len:4
ho 8 tail 4 room 4
load:0x40080404,len:3048
entry 0x40080590
E (386) esp_core_dump_flash: No core dump partition found!
E (386) esp_core_dump_flash: No core dump partition found!


E (386) esp_core_dump_flash: No core dump partition found! indicates that the ESP32 is trying to write a core dump but cannot find the partition. This typically occurs when there is a crash or reset. https://forum.arduino.cc/t/esp32-cam-esp-core-dump-flash/1074812

Ensure the correct partition scheme is selected in the Arduino IDE. Go to Tools > Partition Scheme and select "Huge APP (3MB No OTA)" or another suitable scheme.
No "Huge APP partition scheme" (ESP32)
